# How to pass a value from a controller method to an another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm beginner in MVC3, and I want to get a value from an another controller's method. Here the two methods:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(TennisClub tennisclub)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TennisClubs.Add(tennisclub);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("AssignManager");  
        }

        return View(tennisclub);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AssignManager(Manager manager)
    {

    }
```

So, when I'm creating a new tennis club, Immediately I would like to assign a manager to it... For that I need the primary key "ID".

So my question is: How to get this ID in my "AssignManager" method ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why dont you assign the manager right there when you add the Tennis club?

Comment: Because I need to create it before assign it to the tennis club, Sorry I forget this detail...

Comment: Francesco, just assign by reference, the the data context will take car of this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot *redirect* to an action decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute. That's not how a redirect works. A redirect means that you are sending a 301 HTTP status code to the client with the new Location header and the client issues a GET request to this new location.

So once you remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute from your AssignManager action you could pass the id as parameter:

```
return RedirectToAction("AssignManager", new { id = "123" });
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AssignManager(int id)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return RedirectToAction("AssignManager", new { id = tennisclub.Id });
```

Also you need to remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute from your action

```
public ActionResult AssignManager(int id) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response + 1

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to have a `GET` AssignManager method, too, which would have a parameter telling it to which `TennisClub` the manager should be assigned:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AssignManager(int tennisClubId)
{
    // here, you will want to return AssignManager view
}
```

And when redirecting to `AssignManager` from `Create`, you can specify the id of `TennisClub`:

```
return RedirectToAction("AssignManager", new { tennisClubId = tennisclub.Id });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response + 1